# Azure Devops rest API for create pipeline with source provider bitbucket not working

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-devops-rest-api

I am new on Azure and trying to create pipeline through rest api with below URL
https://dev.azure.com/my-org/my_project/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.1-preview.1

When **Source Provider is Azure Git Repo** then it working perfectly fine with below request body

```
{
  "folder": "\\",
  "name": "Test-Pipeline-1",
  "configuration": {
        "type": "yaml",
        "path":"/azure-pipelines.yml",
        "repository":{
            "id": "1f13f61c-eade-b36bc515bb5e",
             "name": "TestAzure123",
             "type":"azureReposGit"
        }
  }
}
```

But when **Source Provider is Bitbucket Cloud** then its not working

```
{
  "folder": "\\",
  "name": "Bitbucket-Pipeline",
  "configuration": {
        "type": "yaml",
        "path":"/master-pipeline.yaml",
        "repository": {
                "id": "sid_07/Bitbucket-repository",
                "name": "Bitbucket-repository",
                "type": "Bitbucket"
            }
  }
}
```

I am getting below exception

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "This API does not support creating pipelines with repositories of type Unknown.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.UnsupportedRepositoryTypeException, Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "UnsupportedRepositoryTypeException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

Is pipeline creation supported through rest api for bitbucket? or am I missing something? Please help

I have already taken reference from similar issue
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1101376/create-pipeline-rest-api-does-not-work.html

Comment: I tried creating one manually and it forwarded me to bitbucket to authenticate.  I'd recommend maybe creating one manually, their querying the pipeline to see the type it specifies (if you haven't already).  Are you sure the type you've provided is correct?

Comment: @Matt I tried manually first & passing correct type because i am getting this type while collecting repository information from other api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Azure Devops rest API for create pipeline with source provider bitbucket not working

I am afraid the REST API [Pipelines - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) does not support the creation of a pipeline whose source type is `bitbucket` at this moment.

When I use the request body below, which I used to create a pipeline for the resource type of `github`：

```
{
    "folder": "\\",
    "name": "Test-Pipeline-2",
    "configuration": {
        "path": "TestDemo.yml",
        "repository": {
            "fullName": "xxx/leotest",
            "connection": {
                "id": "e11d299a-0bfd-4a38-a77c-xxxxxxxx"
            },
            "type": "bitbucket"
        },
        "type": "yaml"
    }
```

I got the same error as you:

[image]

Then I created that pipeline manually, and use the REST API [Pipelines - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the detailed info about this pipeline, I got following info:

```
"configuration": {
    "path": "BitbucketRepo.yml",
    "repository": null,
    "type": "yaml"
},
"url": "https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxxxx/_apis/pipelines/146?revision=2",
"id": 146,
"revision": 2,
"name": "BitbucketRepo",
"folder": "\\YAML\\Resources"
```

We could to know the part of `repository:` is `null`.

So, the REST API `Pipelines - Create` does not support create pipeline with source provider bitbucket at this moment.

For this request, you could add it for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]