Azure REST API - Create pipeline Issue
I want to create a pipeline using Azure REST API linked with my "GITLAB" (not github) repo -
Using URL - https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=7.0
In Body -
{
  "name": "Gitlab Pipeline",
  "folder": null,
  "configuration": {
    "type": "yaml",
    "path": "/azure-pipelines.yml",
    "repository": {
      "id": "---",
      "type": "Git",
      "name": "---",
      "fullName": "---",
      "url": "---",
      "defaultBranch": "main",
      "connection": {
        "id": "----",
        "name": "---",
        "type": "Git"
      }
    }
  }
}

Getting response as -
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "This API does not support creating pipelines with repositories of type Unknown.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.UnsupportedRepositoryTypeException, Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "UnsupportedRepositoryTypeException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": ---
}

What to do for this, instead of "type": "Git" what can I write

#1 Maybe, microsoft has not added this feature yet : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963855/azure-devops-rest-api-for-create-pipeline-with-source-provider-bitbucket-not-wor #2 Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963855/azure-devops-rest-api-for-create-pipeline-with-source-provider-bitbucket-not-wor  #3 Don't replace sensible values with "---". Replace them with acme-api as repository name. We need the real body to help you #3 Could you try directly with postman? #4 Try with github, share the body to compare  it with bitbucket body

I can reproduce the same error from my side.
According to your scripts, you are trying to create a YAML pipeline based on GitLab repository. Currently, Azure DevOps doesn't support this. You can only create classic build pipelines for your GitLab repository.
I noticed a feature request Allow using yaml build pipelines with Gitlab repositories asking to support YAML pipeline for Gitlab. You can follow it and submit a vote to help increase its priority.
